# Github pages makes download markdown files

Tags: github-pages

I'm creating a github pages website with this tree in my repository:

```
|- pages
|  |- 3.0.3
|  |  |- SUMMARY.md
|  |  |- core
|  |  |  |- String.md
|- LICENSE.md
|- README.md
|- _config.yml
|- index.md
```

In index.md I wrote

```
* [0.3.0](pages/0.3.0/SUMMARY.md)
```

and in `pages/0.3.0/SUMMARY.md`

```
* [String](core/String.md)
```

My problem is this: I can correctly access the main page ('index.md') and `pages/0.3.0/SUMMARY.md`, but when I want to access `String.md`
 generated page, github pages makes me download the file instead of loading the .html page.
What am I doing wrong?

[Here](https://lincas-lang.github.io/LinCAS-API/) is the website and [here](https://github.com/LinCAS-lang/LinCAS-API) my repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your links are incorrect,

- You should use `[String](core/String.html)` URL instead of `[String](core/String.md)`

Because, Jekyll renders `.md` files as `.html`